# Did the transpiler get it wrong?

Tags: javascript, typescript, transpiler, pdf-lib.js

I'm using the pdf-lib package in a TypeScript project and wrote some wrapper code to use it in test automation.  It worked fine. We decided to push this wrapper code to a shared project so others could use it too, but then the test breaks.  After debugging, it seems that the transpiler may have caused the problem.

Pdf-lib's `PDFDict` class has a `get` method that returns a value based on the key parameter. Internally, it is calling `this.dict.get(key)` where `this.dict` is a javascript Map object. The key parameter can be of type any.

When running from our project,
`this.dict.get(key)` returns `FlateDecode`.

When referencing the shared project,
`this.dict.get(key)` returns `undefined`.

When running from our project, the keys in `this.dict` and the `key` object passed into `get` are all `PDFName` objects.

When running from the shared project, the keys in `this.dict` are `PDFName2` objects and the `key` object passed in is a `PDFName3` object.

If my assumption that `get` is returning undefined because the Map key objects and the key passed in are 2 different types (`PDFName2` vs `PDFName3`), did the transpiler screw up here?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say from this somewhat abstract description. Perhaps someone with integral knowledge of that library might know the answer. In any case, recommend giving more information and/or creating a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: maybe pdf-lib has multiple versions running at once?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the kind of bug you get when your code bundler is including multiple versions of a library; and that library isn't equipped to deal with that.

If you're using npm, check your lock file for multiple versions of one package and massage your package file so only one version is used. Resolving this could be very easy or impossible depending on what other dependencies you have.

Comment: The shared project uses yarn.  Its yarn.lock file has a single pdf-lib reference (v. 1.17.1).  My project uses npm and currently has no references to the pdf-lib package.  I actually tried completely deleting both repos locally, then re-adding everything from scratch, but still see the same issue.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you add pdf-lib as a peer dependency instead of a regular dependency? This is probably not what you want, but it's worth trying for the sake of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how, but blowing away my project repo locally, re-cloning it, then re-adding my changes cleared up the issue.